# How to properly unit test Retrofit callbacks with Mockito? MVP and Dagger2 used

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, retrofit, mvp

I download Posts of the users from server using Retrofit and put information into Recycler View. Download is implemented in presenter class and recycler view is located in activity. I would like to test wheter the adapter for Recycler View changes its size after successful response by mocking my web service. What is proper way to do this?

Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Inject
MainActivityPresenter presenter;

@BindView(R.id.postsRecView)
RecyclerView postsRecView;

private PostAdapter postAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //bind views
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    //action bar
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //get dependencies
    ((MainApp)getApplication()).getFragmentComponent().inject(this);
    ((MainApp)getApplication()).getWebServiceComponent().inject(this);

    //set up presenter
    presenter.setActivity(this);

    //when activity created, set up web service communication and download posts
    presenter.setDefaultWebService();
    presenter.downloadPostsList();
}

/**
 * Sets elements (posts) to recycler view list.
 */
public void setUpList(List<Post> posts) {
    postsRecView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    postsRecView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
    postsRecView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    this.postAdapter = new PostAdapter(posts, postsRecView);
    postsRecView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
}

/**
 * Returns adapter of posts.
 * @return PostAdapter
 */
public PostAdapter getAdapter(){
    return postAdapter;
}
}
```

Presenter:

```
public class MainActivityPresenter {

private MainActivity activity;
private WebService service;

@Inject
Retrofit retrofit;

private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

private static final String TAG = "MYAPP";
private static final String TAG_FAIL = "FAIL";

/**
 * Constructor.
 */
@Inject
public MainActivityPresenter (){

}

/**
 * Sets activity.
 * @param activity
 */
public void setActivity(MainActivity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

/**
 * Sets default web service.
 * @return WebService
 */
public WebService setDefaultWebService(){
    WebService service = retrofit.create(WebService.class);
    this.service = service;
    return service;
}

/**
 * Sets web service.
 * @param service
 */
public void setWebService(WebService service) {
    this.service = service;
}

/**
 * Downloads posts and asks the activity to create list of them.
 */
public void downloadPostsList(){

    posts.clear();

    //get new elements
    service.getData().enqueue(new Callback<List<Post>>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Post>> call, Response<List<Post>> response) {

            //assign response objects to list
            posts = response.body();

            //send list objects to the list of activity
            activity.setUpList(posts);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Post>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d(TAG, TAG_FAIL);
        }
    });
}

public WebService getService(){
    return service;
}
}
```

Web service:

```
public interface WebService {

@GET("/users.php")
Call<List<Post>> getData();

}
```

For the present, my test class looks like this, but it throws null pointer exception for the first line of Test:

```
public class MainActivityPresenterTest {

private MainActivityPresenter mMainActivityPresenter;
private MainActivity mMainActivity;

@Mock
private WebService mockedService;

@Mock
private Call<List<Post>> mockedCall;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<Callback<List<Post>>> captor;

@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    //create presenter class
    mMainActivityPresenter = new MainActivityPresenter();

    //create activity class
    mMainActivity = new MainActivity();

    //set activity to presenter
    mMainActivityPresenter.setActivity(mMainActivity);

    //set web service
    mMainActivityPresenter.setWebService(mockedService);
}

@Test
public void testWebServiceResponse(){

    mMainActivityPresenter.downloadPostsList();
    Mockito.verify(mockedService).getData().enqueue(captor.capture());

    List<Post> testPosts = new ArrayList<>();

    Post post1 = new Post();
    Post post2 = new Post();
    Post post3 = new Post();

    testPosts.add(post1);
    testPosts.add(post2);
    testPosts.add(post3);

    captor.getValue().onResponse(mockedCall, Response.success(testPosts));

    assertTrue(mMainActivity.getAdapter().getItemCount() == 3);
}

}
```